# For how long have the great karst springs of the Aachtal been active?

Tags: rivers, paleoclimatology, limestone

Aachtal, along with Lonetal, is a valley in the Swabian Jura, Germany, and the site of many famous archaeological sites of the upper Pleistocene. It also hosts a series of very large karst springs (Aachtopf, Urspingtopf, Blautopf). Have (some of) these springs been active in the upper Pleistocene?